# GUVCviewer - Light frequency filter set default value "50hz" not "NoFliker"

Tags: video, skype, camera

After installing ubuntu 11.10 with noname video camera, video is always very dark. Found the solution. Installed GUVCviewer and changed in settings paremeter - "Light frequency filter" from NoFliker to 50Hz. Unfortunately it has to be done after every restart.

How to set it up permanently?  I think, this is a system parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and solved it with the [Video4Linux Control Panel](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/v4l2ucp) in the Software Center. The changes persist between restarts, and everything 'just works' again.